# Sumifs statement in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, sum, hiveql

I am trying to `sumif` in SQL and getting an accurate result but it is showing everything else as well.

E.g:

```
select brand, sum(if(channel = 'A' and brand in ('001', '002'), orderz, 0)) as conv1
from data.sumifs 
where type IN ('C6', 'C4')
group by channel, brand, orderz, type;
```

This gives me results for brand 001 and 002 correctly along with everything else showing as 0

How do I remove these 0 value rows from table and just receive values for '001' and '002' with sum if statement in SQL?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL. Which database product are you using? SQL is just query language not the name of a specific product

Comment: Okay, so I am using Hive and I think it is DBVisualiser but not sure. And I did run this statement, verified the response and the response is correct. So IF statement doers exist in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause to filter the results:

```
...
WHERE  channel = 'A'
AND    brand IN ('001', '002')
...
```

And that does mean you don't really need the `If()` any more, either!

```
SELECT brand
     , Sum(orderz) AS conv1
FROM   data.sumifs
WHERE  type IN ('C6', 'C4')
AND    channel = 'A'
AND    brand IN ('001', '002')
GROUP
    BY brand
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try this, thanks! Really appreciate it.